# C++11/14: How to remove a pointer-to-member from a type?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

In C++11 or C++1y/14:  Given a value of pointer-to-member type of the form `T C::*` I want to get the pointed-to-type T.

For example:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct T1 { static void f() { cout << "T1" << endl; } };
struct T2 { static void f() { cout << "T2" << endl; } };

struct U1 { T1 x; };
struct U2 { T2 x; };

template<class C> struct V;
template<> struct V<U1> { static constexpr T1 U1::* pm = &U1::x; };
template<> struct V<U2> { static constexpr T2 U2::* pm = &U2::x; };

template<class W>
void f(W pm)
{
     typedef ??? T;
     T::f();
}

int main()
{
        f(V<U1>::pm);
        f(V<U2>::pm);
}
```

Is there a way to do this?  What goes in the `???` above?

**Update:**

Here is a sanitized version of the libstdc++ implementation of `std::remove_pointer`:

```
template<typename T, typename>
struct remove_pointer_helper
{ 
    typedef T type; 
};

template<typename T, typename U>
struct remove_pointer_helper<T, U*>
{ 
    typedef U type; 
};

template<typename T>
struct remove_pointer
    : public remove_pointer_helper<T, typename remove_cv<T>::type>
{};
```

**Update 2:**

Here is the final solution, thanks:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template<typename T, typename>
struct remove_member_pointer_helper
{
    typedef T type;
};

template<typename T, typename U, typename C>
struct remove_member_pointer_helper<T, U C::*>
{
    typedef U type;
};

template<typename T>
struct remove_member_pointer
    : public remove_member_pointer_helper<T, typename remove_cv<T>::type>
{};

template<typename T>
using remove_member_pointer_t = typename remove_member_pointer<T>::type;

struct T1 { static void f() { cout << "T1" << endl; } };
struct T2 { static void f() { cout << "T2" << endl; } };

struct U1 { T1 x; };
struct U2 { T2 x; };

template<class C>
struct V;

template<> struct V<U1> { static constexpr T1 U1::* pm = &U1::x; };
template<> struct V<U2> { static constexpr T2 U2::* pm = &U2::x; };

template<class W>
void f(W pm)
{
        remove_member_pointer_t<W>::f();
}

int main()
{
        f(V<U1>::pm);
        f(V<U2>::pm);
}
```

Comment: You can make a trait that specializes on a pointer-to-member and exposes a type equal to the class type.

Answer (score 10):

This is actually a straightforward exercise in template specialization:

```
template<class T> struct remove_member_pointer {
    typedef T type;
};
template<class C, class T> struct remove_member_pointer<T C::*> {
    typedef T type;
};
```

Comment: @0x499602D2 it wasn't clear to me what the OP actually wanted to do. Anyway, hopefully this answer is illustrative enough for him to adapt it to his own purposes.

Comment: You might mention `template< typename t > using remove_member_pointer_t = typename remove_member_pointer< t >::type;` otherwise this is "merely" C++03.

Comment: @Potatoswatter: `std::remove_member_pointer` doesn't exist in type traits right?  Perhaps it should.

Comment: @AndrewTomazos Don't think there's much call for it. Also, as a generic function, what should it do with PTMFs?

Comment: @Potatoswatter: My need comes from Reflection.  Good question about PTMFs, need to look at that.

Comment: @Potatoswatter: PTMFs seem to work fine: `struct C { void f() {}; }; void (C::*p)() = &C::f; using T = remove_member_pointer_t<decltype(p)>; static_assert(is_same<T, void()>::value, "error");`.  What did you forsee was the problem with them?

Comment: @AndrewTomazos Interesting. The problem is that cv qualification has special meaning for member functions. What happens when you pass one of those in? Only the qualifiers of `p` get stripped, not the function type…

Comment: @Potatoswatter: The cv-qualifiers applying to the function type are kept: `struct C { void f() const {}; }; void (C::*p)() const = &C::f; using T = remove_member_pointer_t<decltype(p)>; static_assert(is_same<T, void() const>::value, "error");`  Three `const` keywords have been added in the previous.

Comment: @AndrewTomazos Again interesting. That use of `void()const` is in accordance with [dcl.fct] 8.3.5/6, last bullet. You're allowed to alias it with a `typedef`, and perhaps use it to forward-declare a member, but little else.

Comment: @Potatoswatter: The utility is that you could strip the const and enumerate the return type / parameters with type deduction.  The point is for reflection.  For example you could enumerate the member functions of a class and generate an RPC client that serializes/deserializes messages, sanity checks the parameters, and then calls the relevant member function.

Comment: @AndrewTomazos Yeah, didn't mean to question the usefulness of uniform metaprocessing. Just that const-qualified function types are relatively unusual, and it's surprisingly nice that the language supports them so elegantly. http://ideone.com/scMNQX